# how to escape empty and/or black field on PDO update?

Tags: php, pdo

i have a tabe with many fields and i want to change one or many fields with the same update method , the problem is when i try to update it affect the others fields that i have not updated too .

this is my sql function :

```
<?php

if ($_REQUEST['fct']=="ModelUpdate") 
{

    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['day'] ) && isset( $_REQUEST['month'] ) && isset( $_REQUEST['year'] ) ) { 

        $D_DATE_NAISSANCE = "".$_REQUEST['year']."/".$_REQUEST['month']."/".$_REQUEST['day']."";

    }else{
        $D_DATE_NAISSANCE = $_REQUEST['model_bidthday'];
    }


    $PK_MODEL  =    isset($_REQUEST['PK_MODEL']) ? $_REQUEST['PK_MODEL'] : $_SESSION['PK_MODEL'];
    $K_KEY_MODEL  = isset($_REQUEST['K_KEY_MODEL']) ? $_REQUEST['K_KEY_MODEL'] : $_SESSION['K_KEY_MODEL'];
    $FK_STUDIO  = $_REQUEST['model_studio'];
    //$S_LOGIN  = $_REQUEST['model_username'];
    //$S_EMAIL  = $_REQUEST['model_adressmail'];
    //$S_PASSWORD  = $_REQUEST['S_PASSWORD'];
    $S_FIRSTNAME  = $_REQUEST['model_firstname'];
    $S_LASTNAME  = $_REQUEST['model_lastname'];
    //$D_DATE_NAISSANCE  = $_REQUEST['model_bidthday'];
    $S_GENRE  = $_REQUEST['model_gender'];
    $S_COUNTRY_CODE  = $_REQUEST['model_coutryCode'];
    $S_CITY  = $_REQUEST['model_city'];
    $S_ZIP  = $_REQUEST['model_zipcode'];
    $S_ADRESS  = $_REQUEST['adress'];
    $S_NATIONALITY  = $_REQUEST['model_nationality'];
    $S_ETHNIE  = $_REQUEST['model_ethnie'];

    $S_CARD_ID_FRONT = $_REQUEST['S_CARD_ID_FRONT'];
    $S_CARD_ID_BACK = $_REQUEST['S_CARD_ID_BACK'];
    $S_IMAGE_CAM = $_POST['S_IMAGE_CAM'];


    $sql = $sqlserver->prepare("UPDATE t_model SET FK_STUDIO=? , S_FIRSTNAME=? , S_LASTNAME=? , D_DATE_NAISSANCE=?, S_GENRE=? ,S_COUNTRY_CODE=?, S_CITY=? , S_ZIP=? , S_ADRESS=? , S_NATIONALITY=? , S_ETHNIE=? , S_CARD_ID_FRONT=?, S_CARD_ID_BACK=? , S_IMAGE_CAM=?   where PK_MODEL=? and K_KEY_MODEL=?");   
    $r = $sql->execute(array($FK_STUDIO,$S_FIRSTNAME,$S_LASTNAME,$D_DATE_NAISSANCE,$S_GENRE,$S_COUNTRY_CODE,$S_CITY,$S_ZIP,$S_ADRESS, $S_NATIONALITY, $S_ETHNIE, $S_CARD_ID_FRONT, $S_CARD_ID_BACK,$S_IMAGE_CAM, $PK_MODEL,$K_KEY_MODEL))  or die(print_r($sql->errorInfo()));              
    $sql->closeCursor();
    echo 1; 

}
?>
```

Comment: The only way to do it, is to generate a dynamic query

Comment: *i try to update it affect the others fields*...please explain what side-effects does it pose to other fields.

Comment: `$sqlserver` implies you're using a Microsoft sql server (Transact-SQL)?

Answer (score 2):

In case you're using an sql server (as the name of the variable suggests) you can use [ISNULL(expr1,expr2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx). In case the parameter in the query is null (expr1) then use the current value of that row (expr2).

```
// using php7's Null coalescing operator
// for php < 7 use: isset($_REQUEST['key']) ? $_REQUEST['key'] : replacement
$PK_MODEL  = $_REQUEST['PK_MODEL'] ?? $_SESSION['PK_MODEL'];
$K_KEY_MODEL  = $_REQUEST['K_KEY_MODEL'] ?? $_SESSION['K_KEY_MODEL'];
$FK_STUDIO  = $_REQUEST['model_studio'] ?? NULL;
$S_FIRSTNAME  = $_REQUEST['model_firstname'] ?? NULL;
$S_LASTNAME  = $_REQUEST['model_lastname'] ?? NULL;
$S_GENRE  = $_REQUEST['model_gender'] ?? NULL;
$S_COUNTRY_CODE  = $_REQUEST['model_coutryCode'] ?? NULL;
$S_CITY  = $_REQUEST['model_city'] ?? NULL;
$S_ZIP  = $_REQUEST['model_zipcode'] ?? NULL;
$S_ADRESS  = $_REQUEST['adress'] ?? NULL;
$S_NATIONALITY  = $_REQUEST['model_nationality'] ?? NULL;
$S_ETHNIE  = $_REQUEST['model_ethnie'] ?? NULL;
$S_CARD_ID_FRONT = $_REQUEST['S_CARD_ID_FRONT'] ?? NULL;
$S_CARD_ID_BACK = $_REQUEST['S_CARD_ID_BACK'] ?? NULL;
$S_IMAGE_CAM = $_POST['S_IMAGE_CAM'] ?? NULL;


$sql = $sqlserver->prepare("
    UPDATE
        t_model
    SET
        FK_STUDIO=IsNull(?,FK_STUDIO),
        S_FIRSTNAME=IsNull(?,S_FIRSTNAME),
        S_LASTNAME=IsNull(?,S_LASTNAME),
        D_DATE_NAISSANCE=IsNull(?,D_DATE_NAISSANCE),
        S_GENRE=IsNull(?,S_GENRE),
        S_COUNTRY_CODE=IsNull(?,S_COUNTRY_CODE),
        S_CITY=IsNull(?,S_CITY),
        S_ZIP=IsNull(?,S_ZIP),
        S_ADRESS=IsNull(?,S_ADRESS),
        S_NATIONALITY=IsNull(?,S_NATIONALITY),
        S_ETHNIE=IsNull(?,S_ETHNIE),
        S_CARD_ID_FRONT=IsNull(?,S_CARD_ID_FRONT),
        S_CARD_ID_BACK=IsNull(?,S_CARD_ID_BACK),
        S_IMAGE_CAM=IsNull(?,S_IMAGE_CAM)
    WHERE
        PK_MODEL=?
        AND K_KEY_MODEL=?
");
```

In case you're using MySQL, the same can be done via [I**F**NULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull]).
Either way it's cruical that the server really gets a NULL-value (not only an empty string but NULL).

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use dynamically created queries.

You'll have to have the input fields' names the same as your columns in the table that you're going to update.
Then pass all the variables to the superglobal `$_POST` this way you won't update anything that is empty. 
In your update function loop through `$_POST` like this:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE t_model SET ';
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    if($value !== '' && !empty($value)) //checking if you don't have an empty value and you can add more exceptions here by doing '&& $key !== 'exception' or '&& $value !== "exception"'
        $sql .= $key.' = :'.$key.', ';
}
$sql = rtrim($sql, ",")." where PK_MODEL=:PK_MODEL and K_KEY_MODEL=:K_KEY_MODEL ";
$query = $sqlserver->prepare($sql);
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    if($value !== '' && !empty($value)){
        $query->bindValue(':'.$key, $value);
    }
}
$query->execute();
$query->closeCursor();
echo 1;
```

This should work, I've been using the same structure for my dynamic admin panel and it works like a charm.

*NOTE*: I've changed some variable names to make it a little bit easier to read for potential other users
**IMPORTANT EDIT:** As suggested by @SZenC this could be vulnerable to SQL injection. This would be by adding input fields manually in the source code of the form.
This can all be prevented by adding an additional check in the loops like this:

```
$allowed_cols = array('col1', 'col2', 'col3');
if($value !== '' && !empty($value) && in_array($key, $allowed_cols)){
```

So the fix for this potential SQL injection is to edit the checks in the for loops

Comment: This is a really bad idea, as it is vulnerable to SQL-inject attacks

Comment: As far as I know it is not. We're using Prepared statements here, the only way would be by adding input fields, and for that OP could set a check on the allowed columns using an array. I will edit my answer to cover this.

Comment: Imagine I send the `$_POST`-variable `;DROP DATABASE--=SOME VALUE` in post to this script. It would prepare the query ` UPDATE t_model SET ; DROP DATABASE-- where ....`. This is relatively easy to solve, you just have to implement a filter on the allowed keys in your `$_POST`

Comment: @SZenC This wouldn't work since the whole point of prepared statements is to put pass all the user input as plain text, so pure data, for example try putting the mysql function 'NOW()' in a prepared statement by binding the value, you will see that it won't return the actual time since it is escaped to pure data

Comment: I know, that's the purpose of a prepared statement, but your code (before the edit) still allows me to insert code before it is converted to a prepared statement. I could inject the SQL-commands BEFORE you make it prepared. That is your vuln.

Comment: @SZenC You're right thanks for pointing it out, by using the allowed cols array it should be safe enough, and you could even elaborate by passing each key through a regular expression that removes all special characters